# Remote private repo does not seem private

Tags: visual-studio, github

I am testing if my remote private repo at Github is indeed only accessible by me.

So I created this private repo at github.com: https://github.com/leonvanr/test2

I logged out of github, and logged out of Visual Studio 2017.

The problem is I am able to clone this repo. Am I forgetting something?

Inside Visual Studio Clone the remote repo:

[image]

clone succeeded:

[image]

the one file read me in Solution Explorer:

[image]

Comment: "The problem is I am able to clone this repo"—how, exactly, are you doing this? That repo is private, but if you're authenticating with an SSH key or have cached HTTPS credentials you may still be able to clone it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to clone it and after entering my github credentials I got the message `fatal: repository 'https://github.com/leonvanr/test2/' not found`.

Comment: @Chris I have added three images to illustrate the cloning process. I am not aware of and SSH key or cached credentials, so that will be the default settings. Can I look this up somewhere so I can provide you that info?

Comment: @MikeFaber At github.com I also get a 404, so that is ok. The problem is I can clone it with Visual Studio.

Comment: @leonvr, I'm not very familiar with Visual Studio, but you must have authenticated with GitHub through its Git integration at some point. You're probably still logged in through VS, or it's cached your credentials, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably found out what was the case.

In my Windows 10 -> Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials, I deleted two GitHub-rows.

Now, if I try to clone the remote repo, I am prompted for Github credentials. So I assume that if that were someone else's credentials, the cloning would be refused.

@Chris, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.